# how to send particular row data to next jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

When I press submit it should send the details of that particular row to next jsp.I searched for similar questions but no one answered it correctly or their answers are not applicable to my doubt , so please check the code and help me, Thank you.

```
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(vsql);
while(rs.next())
{
%>
<tr>
<td><%=rs.getString(14)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>   
<td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
<td><form action="Followup2.jsp"><input type="submit" value="submit">[I][1]
</form></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the data as hidden inputs:

```
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(vsql);
while(rs.next())
{
%>
<tr>
<td><%=rs.getString(14)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>   
<td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
<td><form action="Followup2.jsp">
<input type="hidden" name="col14" value="<%=rs.getString(14)%>" />
<input type="hidden" name="col1" value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>" />
<input type="hidden" name="col2" value="<%=rs.getString(2)%>" />
<input type="hidden" name="col3" value="<%=rs.getString(3)%>" />
<input type="submit" value="submit">[I][1]
</form></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: then how to get them in next jsp ?

Comment: In the parameters